# How to input 2 items in a record

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if there was a way to input 2 items into an array (2 dimensional) at least. One part of the array to hold the name of the person that was golfing, and the other part of the array to hold the score of the person that was playing.

```
scores = []
playerName = "Cynthia"
playerScore = "72"
scoreEntry = [playerName, playerScore]
```

The code above shows it being hard coded into it so the resulting would be **[Cynthia, 72]**, but I am trying to figure out how to grab the input from the user and tried applying directly to the array, but it ends up coming out to this below.

```
How many players: 1
Enter a name: Cynthia
Enter a score: 72
Data written out is:  C : y

Data written out is:  7 : 2
```

This is the output im currently getting
Code below for what I used to get this

```
def main():
    golfFile = open ("golf.dat", 'w')
    scores = []
    SIZE = getSize()
    playerName = getName(scores, SIZE)
    playerScore = getScore(scores, SIZE)
    scoreEntry = [playerName, playerScore]
    scores.append(scoreEntry)

    for scoreEntry in scores:
        fileLine = scoreEntry [0] + " : " + str(scoreEntry [1]) + "\n"
        golfFile.write (fileLine)
        print("Data written out is: ", fileLine)
    golfFile.close()

def getSize():
    SIZE = int(input("How many players: "))
    return SIZE

def getName(scores, SIZE):
    index = 0
    while (index <= SIZE - 1):
        nameInput = input("Enter a name: ")
        scores.append(nameInput)
        index = index + 1
    return scores

def getScore(scores, SIZE):
    index = 0
    while(index <= SIZE - 1):
        scoreInput = input("Enter a score: ")
        scores.append(scoreInput)
        index = index + 1
    return scores
main()
```

Expected output is

> [Cynthia, 72]

There is an error that comes up as well

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programs\test.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\Programs\test.py", line 11, in main
    fileLine = scoreEntry [0] + " : " + str(scoreEntry [1]) + "\n"
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Also, I do not want to use any libraries at all for this

Answer (score 0):

You're appending to `scores` in the `getName()` and `getScore()` functions, and each of them return the whole `scores` list. Then you're putting those two references to `scores` in the `scoreEntry` list, and then appending that list to `scores` again. So you've got the lists nested several levels deep, and you never have each name in the same list as the corresponding score.

Instead, you should just read one name and score each time through a single loop. Put those in a `scoreEntry` tuple, and append that to the `scores` list.

```
def main():
    scores = []
    SIZE = getSize()
    for _ in range(SIZE):
        playerName = getName()
        playerScore = getScore()
        scoreEntry = (playerName, playerScore)
        scores.append(scoreEntry)
    
    with open ("golf.dat", 'w') as golfFile:
        for scoreEntry in scores:
            fileLine = scoreEntry [0] + " : " + str(scoreEntry [1]) + "\n"
            golfFile.write (fileLine)
            print("Data written out is: ", fileLine)

def getSize():
    SIZE = int(input("How many players: "))
    return SIZE

def getName():
    nameInput = input("Enter a name: ")
    return nameInput

def getScore():
    scoreInput = int(input("Enter a score: "))
    return scoreInput

main()
```

Comment: i am curious in a way as well, how would this work with the 2nd pass through, because I seem to get an error with that, index out of range

Comment: What do you mean by 2nd pass through?

Comment: oh, i seem to get this error whenever i put a 2nd player inside

Comment: fileLine = scoreEntry [0] + " : " + str(scoreEntry [1]) + "\n"
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I ran my script with 5 players and it was fine

Comment: I don't think you copied my answer correctly. I changed `scoreEntry` from a list to a tuple, so the error would be `tuple index out of range`